# How to activate python in cygwin?

Tags: python, anaconda, cygwin

I tried to activate python in cygwin by using `python -i` but the following error occurred:

```
 Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/
```

So i went to conda.io and i did `conda activate + c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\` and it worked apparently.However when i came back to cygwin the error remains.Anyone here know the solution to this?Thanks!

Comment: Can you try ? 
c:\cygwin\bin\python -i
From the window where you activated conda.

Comment: I tried `python -i C:\cygwin64\bin` but it said `ImportError: No module named __main__`

Comment: Cygwin has its own Python. Do not mix the two installations. $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9

Comment: They may want to use conda from a Cygwin shell.  I do it all th time, but it's often a bit buggy (since obviously the conda people don't test this).

Comment: What do you mean by "when i came back to cygwin the error remains".  `conda activate` is a shell command that modifies your environment, so you have to set up all the conda shell commands to work in in your Cygwin shell.  As I wrote above this can be made to work, but the scripts that come with conda are a little buggy sometimes on Cygwin so you have to know what you're doing.

Comment: Hi @Iguananaut.I already solved my problem.It was because i didn't installed python when i installed cygwin.But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Usage is `python3 -i <script file>`  python will enter interactive mode after executing the python script named <script-file>.